# Get data for fiscal year from table without date columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a query (purpose: manual DB testing) that would get the rows of the previous/current/next Fiscal Year and then the SUM(turnover)

---

**Given**

(1) the below table,

and

(2) Fiscal Year (FY) = March to February

**When** Previous FY --  **Then** 2 rows: 2016/1 to 2016/2

**When** Current FY -- **Then** 12 rows: from 2016/3 to 2017/2 (year/month)

**When** Future FY -- **Then**  1 row: 2017/3

```
+--------------+---------------+----------+
|  Year (num)  |  Month (num)  | Turnover |
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     1         |   1000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     2         |   2000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     3         |   3000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     4         |   4000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     5         |   2000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     6         |   1000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     7         |   2000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     8         |   1000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     9         |   2000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     10        |   3000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     11        |   4000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2016         |     12        |   5000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2017         |     1         |   6000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2017         |     2         |   2000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2017         |     3         |   1000   | 
+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

The best solution I came up with is the below query and change the `Year` values to switch between years. It feels hacky to me because of creating an extra solumn with sysdate and checking for NOT NULL. Is there a more elegant way?

```
WITH CTE AS (

SELECT 
CASE
WHEN Month BETWEEN 3 AND 12 AND Year = 2016                                            
THEN sysdate
WHEN Month BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND Year = 2017
THEN sysdate
END case_statement_date, 

year, month, turnover, FROM Table

 )

SELECT sum(turnover) FROM CTE  
 WHERE  case_statement_date IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Did you even read the question? Sample data = that big table in the middle. Desired results: When - Then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select year + (case when month >= 3 then 0 else -1 end) as fiscal_year,
       sum(turnover)
from t
group by year + (case when month >= 3 then 0 else -1 end) ;
```

Comment: Almost, sum(turnover) instead of count(*). Thanks, will accept as correct answer when it will become possible.